# After configuring virtual hosts still get 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, ubuntu-12.04

Ok, so I'm trying to setup Symfony 2 demo application on my local machine. I use apache 2.2 web-server and I downloaded project's files into my ~/myproject/ directory (in my Home folder). As Symfony documentation reccomends here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html I created file "myproject" in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ with following contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName myproject
ServerAlias www.myproject

DocumentRoot /home/dmitriy/myproject/web
  <Directory /home/dmitriy/myproject/web>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

I disabled default apache config and enabled "myproject" by running

```
sudo a2dissite default && sudo a2ensite mysite
```

after that I restarted apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now, symfony demo project ships with .htaccess file in web/ directory and here is its contents:

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

In my understanding I should now be able to see the project's index page by address "www.myproject" or just "myproject" right? Because of these two lines

```
ServerName myproject
ServerAlias www.myproject
```

but that doesn't work, and when I try that the browser shows some google results. When I try to prepend localhost/ I get 404 and only when I type localhost/app_dev.php or localhost/config.php I can see the real pages but it is not the way it should work is it? Something is wrong and apparently I made a mistake at some point but I lack experience and to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to edit my /etc/hosts file. After adding `127.0.0.1 myproject www.myproject` it finally worked!